# Inserting a directive from another directive's compile function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, append, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I want to dynamically insert the `<confirmation>` element in the DOM from the updater directive. (I have it setup to tap into an event, which it does in my real app) I just need that element inserted and then it'll have the same functionality (as defined in it's respective directive).

Some background: I've tried appending the element and then using the $compile service - `$compile(element)(scope)`, but I think $compile inside a directive's compile function doesn't work. and appending without $compile gives it no angular bindings.

Here's an *updated* Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/OyBTYGTkMtxryFdDRwQN?p=preview

anyway I can do that? any help would be deeply appreciated even if it's pointing me to the right directon.

Comment: Your plunkr is broken (so it clearly fails to demonstrate the problem). Besides that, everything should work fine. You are not `$compile`ing from the compile function of a directive, but from the postLink function btw.

Comment: Hello ExpertSystem, sorry about that I've updated the plnkr link and it works. Can you look at the code and help me out with a solution? thanks

Comment: Still broken ! Attempts remaining: 1

Comment: Good for you ! You didn'e have any attempts left :D

Comment: Can someone please help me  find a solution for this?

Comment: You said you solved it. Now you deleted that comment and ask for help to solve it ?!

Comment: No Sir, my comment was taken totally out of context, I was talking about the Plnkr working, not the solution of the problem I posted. I deleted the comment so it does not lead to further confusion.

Comment: I suggest, you create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sure, here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OyBTYGTkMtxryFdDRwQN?p=preview
The grey text is appended via the directive and I need it to have it's respective `confirmation` directive behavior.

Comment: It is still unclear what the problem is. What behavior is not present ?

Comment: Hello ExpertSystem, I've updated a plnkr in my post above, which states in detail what I'm trying to achieve I'm sorry if I was vague in my earlier plnkr. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `compile` property of the *Directive Definition Object* in the `appender` directive. You just need the `$compile` service to compile a new `<confirmation>` element.
Furthermore, you might want to specify the properties of the isolate scope (i.e. `message` and/or `state`):

```
.directive('appender', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.after($compile('<confirmation message="..."></confirmation>')(scope));
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/TanvCnLNEBM25t9l6TjQ?p=preview)**.

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments, it is obvious you do not understand the concepts of compiling and linking. Although, you think you are using the `compile` property, in fact all you need is the linking function. I strongly suggest you take a closer look at **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)** regarding the Directive Definition Object.

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('items', function(val, oldVal) {
            if (val === oldVal) { return; }
            element.after($compile('<confirmation message="..."></confirmation>')(scope));
        }, true);
    }
};
```

See, also, this other **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BvPOvBzMddcwSgn3I9MY?p=preview)**.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Since you are so insistent on compiling from the other directive's `compile` function,
here is the code:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function () {
        var compiled = $compile('<confirmation message="..."></confirmation>');
        return function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('items', function(val, oldVal) {
                if (val === oldVal) { return; }
                elem.after(compiled(scope));
            }, true);
        };
    }
};
```

and here is the **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qlib2s6gM7boxismej1b?p=preview)**.

Comment: I need it to fire from a compile function inside the directive, as it has a `$watch`er which listens for a change in value and then inserts this directive. That's the problem I've been facing, trying to run $compile in a compile function doesn't seem to work. I need access to both the $scope and scope .

Comment: There is no point in `$compile`ing from a `compile` function, because you can't link (there is no scope which is necessary for linking). Are you sure you understand what the `compile` and `linking` phases are in a directive lifecycle ?

Comment: Yes I understand but I'm pretty lost after trying so much to get this to work tbh. how would I go about having to bind it from the `compile` function itself, It watches for a condition there and only then takes action. Really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: You can't watch anything in a compile function. Why don't you create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem (e.g. also contains the watch you are talking about) ?

Comment: Hello ExpertSystem, I've tried to simulate the event in the update plnkr Link above. It has a watch event too which fires an alert and changes the data, that's when I want to append my element. Please have a look? You can almost sense how desperate I am to get this to work. :P

Comment: @SinSync: I updated the answer. Please, take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much for that and I would concede not being too clear on the concepts, I did manage to use compile in the link function but I wanted to find out a way I could do it in the compile fucntion, that's the reason why I mentioned compile func. However I'll mark the answer as correct for your assistance and patience right from the beginning haha. Thanks.

Comment: @SinSync: I really believe that your insisting on compiling in the compile function is due to lack of in-depth understanding of the concepts involved. Nonetheless, you have every right to wish unreasonable things for your app. So, I updated the answer with an alternative implementation that compiles in the compile function.

Comment: Yes I did find myself in a position where I just had to find a way to do that in the `compile` function, nothing bad in the odd hack. :P I have been reading the docs to get a deeper understanding of the concepts nonetheless. You have been an absolute legend! :D